# Axios POST getting 500 (Internal Server Error) with ReactJS and Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

im a newbie in reactJs and laravel. So the problem that i have is i tried to register a new user from my front end to my backend which is laravel. I also use laravel/sanctum because i wanted to make the an SPA website. I tried making an HTTP request with axios and its giving me 500 error status. this is my axios post code

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [password_confirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState("");

  const record = JSON.stringify({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    password_confirmation,
  });


  const store = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register", record, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "aplication/json" },
      })
      .then(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err.response.data);
      });
  };
```

my laravel api routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/me', MeController::class);
    Route::post('/logout', LogoutController::class);
});
```

and register controller which i made it with invoke method

```
 public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $attribute = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);


        $attributes['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
        User::create($attributes);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "You're Registered"
        ]);
    }
```

when i sent the request through register button, i see an error in the network section through inspect page which shown like this

```
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "D:\File Kuliah\project\backend.mention\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
line: 678
message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ($2y$10$T0YA.BboEcPDVQm7eIG6kuwybwnPo.tsG.bBkhOhBx54Y5tRWXaBG, 2021-04-08 17:07:09, 2021-04-08 17:07:09))"
```

i thought the problem was because of the CORS in sanctum which i tried to set the `'support_credential' => true` in the cors.php file but it actually did nothing.

Comment: Looking at the error it seems the `name` field isn't set correctly, possibly being an empty string or null. Which it doesn't support by default. You can use `dd()` to die-n-dump the attributes to see what's you're getting.

Comment: You're assigning the clean request to `$attribute`, then attempt to use `$attributes` below it. You don't get an error because you create the variable when you encrypt your password.

Answer (score 3):

Looking closely at your code you've misspelled the `$attributes` variable you pass into your `User::create`. Removing the `s` should fix it.

```
 public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $attribute = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        ]);


        $attribute['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        User::create($attribute);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "You're Registered"
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: thank you , i'm ashamed that the problem was just a misspell

Comment: Misspelled variable names are really common, nothing to be ashamed of. 

Comment: @charint4 there is nothing to be felt ashamed of.. common cheer up ..Just as the saying goes..."As humans, we're going to make mistakes. It's what makes us human, and most of the time, the most effective way of learning is from a mistake"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this....by adding name and  email field...

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
        {
            $attribute = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string',
                'email' => 'required|string|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
            ]);
            
           $attribute['password'] = bcrypt($request->password); 
    
           
            User::create($attribute);
    
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "You're Registered"
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: there is a misspelled `$attributes` variable which should be `$attribute`. There is no way what you did there would work correctly and safely. Just replace `User::create($attributes);` with `User::create($attribute);` and it's done

Comment: @CornelRaiu thanks for pointing that out... thank you so much..I am upvoting the above answer

Comment: that is not my answer :) but yes, that one is and was the first correct  answer

Comment: @CornelRaiu sorry i thought it was you your answer...any way so much thankful to you for correcting me ...

Comment: Actually i tried the solution above your solution, it was just a misspelled variable. Though thank you for your response